# dynamodb.put(...).promise.then is not a function in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, backend

I'm getting an error while adding the data to dynamodb AWS server from postman, I have created API using API gateway and lambda in AWS.
status 502 bad gateway and
{
"message": "Internal server error"
}.

[click here to watch the codeimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLW1D.png)
I added this function but did not get where it went wrong
imported dynamoDB using documenClient only still there was an error "const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();"

Let me know where it went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, but properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: Check out your Cloudwatch logs for your Lambda function.  That may give you a more detailed error message than 502.

Answer (score -1):

`.promise` is a function. So you need to call it (e.g. `promise()`) so it can return a promise.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html